# How to avoid many 'if's' and provide runtime params on execution

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, architecture

I am trying to avoid lots of `if's` and use an OOP way to execute different executions. the execution is determined by ACTION integer which I get from an API on runtime.

I though about command pattern and this is how it looks:

I created on Spring configuration a hashmap:

```
      @Bean
        public HashMap<Integer, Command> hashmapCommands() {
            HashMap<Integer, Command> supportedCommands = new HashMap<>();
            supportedCommands.put(command.action.getId(), myCommand());
            ..
    }

  @Bean
    public Command MyCommand() {
        return new myCommand();
    }


public class MyCommand implements Command {

    public final static ACTION action = 1;
   @Override
    public void execute(String runTimeData) {
      //doSomeLogic
    }

}
```

Now on some other place on my case I am injecting hashmapCommands:

on inoker class:

```
public class TestCommands(){
..
 supportedCommands = (HashMap<Integer, Command>) context.getBean("hashmapCommands");
...

public void someTest(){
 Command myCommand = supportedCommands.get(1);
 reportCommandBase.execute("some runtimeMessage");
}
```

I have params inside execution()  it's wrong to use that using Command pattern.

As you can see I must send runtime message and avoiding if statements which retrieve the command execution from hashmap. But i need to sent param which I am getting only on runtime.

Mybe i am forcing Command pattern on my case?  other suggestions ?

Comment: Please clarify "But i need to sent param which I am getting only on runtime". What does that mean? Where do these parameters come from? Why doesn't the command itself get the params it needs?

Comment: The runtime message which i send to the command is retrieved from client side. i cant populated it in advanced. i must use it on MyCommand execute() logic

Comment: i have a message listener that get client side calls and that listeners calling different commands upon thr api action type.

Comment: So, pass the message you receive in the listener to your command. What's the problem?

Comment: how do you pass it to the command? via execute?  thats what I do. but it's violating the Command pattern. I am getting side effects when consumer actually influencing the command

Comment: Then don't call that a Command, and call it something else. You'll have something that does what you want, works fine, and is not the command pattern.

Comment: if you have too many if/else, I mean too many, in your execute method, you probably want to separate the command into different sub-commands and call different ones accordingly.

Comment: @jb dont you think that Strategy will work here? ofcourse i am not forcing a design-pattern to my code. just my code became very complicated.

Comment: @ShawnSong could answer the question with an example according to your comment? I am not sure I understand that.