# Command Pattern with Generic Return Type

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, design-patterns, command-pattern

I'm trying to implement the `Command Pattern` with a generic return type in Java.

After [reviewing this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669326/java-generic-return-type) I created a `Command` class (interface) that looks like this:

```
public interface Command <T> {

    T execute(ArrayList<String> list, T type);
}

public class SearchResultsPage implements Command{

    @Override
    public <T extends List<ProductPOJO>>  T execute(ArrayList<String> list, T type) {

    List<ProductPOJO> productPOJOList = generatePOJOFromSearch(list);

    type.addAll(productPOJOList);

    return type;
    }
}
```

However, Eclipse keeps complaining that:

> The method execute(ArrayList, T) of type SearchResultsPage
>   must override or implement a supertype method

But when I click

> Create execute() in supertype Command

Eclipse automatically generates the method `T execute(ArrayList<String> list, T type);` in `Command` class (i.e, exact same signature as what I created) yet the error message does not go away.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: The Command Pattern does not accept arguments to its `execute()` method. See: [How to use Command pattern by passing to it runtime params?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36187330/1371329) It's perfectly fine to add the parameter to your code; just be aware that it doesn't follow the GoF Command Pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of the `execute` method is incorrect.  You've made the interface generic with the `T` type parameter, but you don't supply a type argument when implementing it in the concrete class `SearchResultsPage`.  This means you've implemented the raw form of the interface.  Instead, you've made the method itself generic, when it isn't generic in the interface.

Move the declaration of `T` in the class method to the class itself.

```
public class SearchResultsPage<T extends List<ProductPOJO>> implements Command<T> {
    @Override
    public T execute(ArrayList<String> list, T type) {
        // ...
    }
}
```